# Connection pooling in node-mongodb-native, when to call db.open and db.close

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, connection-pooling

I've read most questions here about [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) but I can't work out the standard practice as to when I should open/close a connection.

Some sources say open/close as needed, some say use one db instance throughout. Does node-mongodb-native support automatic connection pooling? If so, how do I use this?

I would really appreciate example code showing correct use of `db.open` and `db.close` in relation to, say, a login request.

Comment: I know this is old, but there's an example using generic-pool here:
https://github.com/dave-elkan/layered-express And about using poolSize options, there are more info here:
http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/server.html

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use [generic-pool](https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool)

It's very clear and pretty straightforward, you define how to open connection, how to close, and size of the pool. The module takes care of the rest, creating new connections as needed, and disposing unused connection after timeout you also select.

I use the module with every resource I need to pool, so I dont have to bother with custom pooling API every time.

Comment: Have you used it successfully with mongodb?

Comment: yes, of course, but this is _generic_ pool module, you can use it literally with _any_ resource

Comment: This should not be necessary. MongoDB native driver already does connection pooling internally.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best answer I could find. Apparently, it works automatically, but I'm still figuring out the details.

Let me know if you find anything!

[http://technosophos.com/node/255](http://web.archive.org/web/20131006193348/http://technosophos.com/node/255)